# Spherical harmonics and irreducible representations of $SO(2)$ and $SO(3)$

Tags: representation-theory, spherical-harmonics

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Connection_with_representation_theory) article it is mentioned (without source) that the spherical harmonics of degree $\ell$ on the $n$-sphere are an irreducible (whether real or complex is not mentioned) representations of $SO(n+1,\mathbb{R})$.

**Spherical harmonics**

How I define the space of spherical harmonics: Let $H^{(\ell)}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ be the (real or complex) vector space of harmonic homogeneous polynomials of degree $\ell$ in $(n+1)$ real variables. The (real or complex) vector space of spherical harmonics of degree $\ell$ on the $n$-sphere is defined by restricting the polynomials $h(x)$ in $H^{(\ell)}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ to $x \in S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and is denoted by $H_\mathbb{R}^{(\ell)}(S^n)$ and $H_\mathbb{C}^{(\ell)}(S^n)$.

**First question**

For $n=1$ the spaces $H_\mathbb{R}^{(m)}(S^1)$ and $H_\mathbb{C}^{(m)}(S^1)$ have (real or complex) dimension $2$ for $m \ge 1$. I know that all non-trivial irreducible *real* representations of $SO(2, \mathbb{R})$ have dimension $2$ and all irreducible *complex* representations have dimension $1$. I understand that $H_\mathbb{R}^{(m)}(S^1)$ is an irreducible *real* representation of $SO(2, \mathbb{R})$, but most certainly is $H_\mathbb{C}^{(m)}(S^1)$ not an irreducible *complex* representation of $SO(2, \mathbb{R})$ (by dimensional arguments). So is the above statement false?

**Second question**

For $n=2$ the spaces $H_\mathbb{R}^{(\ell)}(S^2)$ and $H_\mathbb{C}^{(\ell)}(S^2)$ have (real or complex) dimension $2\ell+1$. I understand that $H_\mathbb{C}^{(\ell)}(S^2)$ is an irreducible *complex* representation of $SO(3, \mathbb{R})$ and a suitable basis are the spherical harmonics. Is $H_\mathbb{R}^{(\ell)}(S^2)$ an irreducible *real* representation of $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ with a suitable basis the [real spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Real_form)? I see no obstruction but it is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748772/what-is-the-real-representation-theory-of-so3) that there might be problems since $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed.

Comment: See the section 3 and other sections of the thesis-http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edixhovensj/teaching/2019-2020/CIMPA/benthem_bsc_thesis.pdf

Comment: As far as I understand the thesis is only concerned with irreducible complex representations of $SO(3)$ and thus does not answer my second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I found the answers myself.

**First question**

The statement that the spherical harmonics of degree $\ell$ on the $n$-sphere are irreducible *complex* representations of $SO(n+1,\mathbb{R})$ holds for $n \ge 2$ which answers the first question. Also I might add that in general these are not all irreducible *complex* representations, but only those of highest weight $(\ell, 0, \dots, 0)$. About irreducible *real* representations I have not found a similar statement yet.

**Second question**

The universal (double) cover $SU(2, \mathbb{C})$ has irreducible real representations in all dimensions which are odd or divisible by $4$, see e.g. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499190023U). As in the complex case, the irreducible real representations in odd dimensions descend to $SO(3, \mathbb{R})$ and are isomorphic to $H_\mathbb{R}^{(\ell)}(S^2)$.